# Redux - Can't access store for Next.js pages in Page Router

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am using Next 13.4 and trying to connect pages in the Page Router to my redux store.  When trying to call the store in a page, I get the following error:

```
#### test.jsx
Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>

> 5 | const storeData = useSelector((state) => state.topNftEth.topNftEthData);
```

Here are the other pieces of code (removed non-relevant code):

```
#### Folder Structure
\src
  \app
    -layout.tsx
    -pages.tsx
  \pages
    -test.jsx
  \redux
    \features
    -provider.tsx
    -store.ts
```

```
#### layout.tsx
"use client";
import "./globals.css";
import { Providers } from "./../redux/provider";

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <Providers>
        <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
      </Providers>
    </html>
  );
}
```

```
#### provider.tsx
"use client";

import { store } from "./store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

export function Providers({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>;
}
```

```
#### test.jsx
"use client";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

export default function Test() {
  const storeData = useSelector((state) => state.NFTData);

  return <h2>COOL STUFF</h2>;
}
```

I was hoping that wrapping the layout.tsx page will cover pages within the Pages folder (page router), but perhaps it doesnt.  All my components and the page.tsx file is able to call the Redux store no problem.

Any ideas on how to ensure routes in the Page Router can access the Redux Store?

Comment: _"I was hoping that wrapping the layout.tsx page will cover pages within the Pages folder"_ - It does not. Why do you not move the `test` page to the `app` folder too?

Comment: @juliomalves thanks for helping me find a solution - when I tried moving the test.jsx to the app folder, I was still getting the same issue.

However when creating a separate page.tsx and layout.tsx file for each of the routes, I am able to access the redux store!